# Encrypt loggingConfiguration using enterprise library configuration tool either for one server or to use with web farm

Tags: encryption, enterprise-library-5

I want to encrypt the information in `loggingConfiguration` section in `web.config` using enterprise library configuration tool to work on one server or on web farm

I used many ways but it didn't work.

I tried to encrypt the connection string and it worked fine.

Comment: It is unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650762.aspx):

> You can encrypt and decrypt the data in a configuration file's
> configuration sections. A configuration section contains the
> configuration information for an application block.
>
> The configuration
> tool allows you to select from the encryption providers that are
> included in the Machine.config file. Typically, these are the
> DataProtectionConfigurationProvider, which uses DPAPI, and the
> RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, which uses RSA.
>
> If the encrypted
> configuration file is going to be on only a single server, you can use
> the DataProtectionConfigurationProvider.
>
> If you want to deploy the
> same encrypted configuration file on multiple servers in a Web farm,
> you should use the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider. This provider
> makes it easy for you encrypt the data on one server computer and then
> export the RSA private key needed to decrypt the data. You can then
> deploy the configuration file and the exported key to the target
> servers, and then re-import the keys.
>
> To encrypt a configuration
> section Open one of the configuration tools. Open an existing
> configuration file or create a new one. Click the name of the
> application block whose configuration information you want to encrypt.
> In the Properties pane, click ProtectionProvider. Select either
> DataProtectionConfigurationProvider or
> RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.
>
> All the settings for the providers,
> such as where keys are stored, are also in the Machine.config file.
> You cannot change this file with a configuration tool. Instead, you
> must modify the file using a text editor. To decrypt a configuration
> file, simply open it in the configuration tool. The file is
> automatically decrypted.

[image]